# How to implement the function?

Tags: erlang

I'm trying to implement the following function:

```
person(Name, Age, Address) -> Person.
```

Where `Name` is a string, `Age` is an integer and `Address` is a string

Function should return map(Person) that contains data in the function argument:

```
person("Kermit the frog", 60, "123 Sesame street").
```

I know how to implement it with records:

```
person1() -> #person{name = "Kermit the Frog",
                     age = 60,
                     address = "123 Sesame Street"}.
```

but I need the function to return a map instead.

Any suggestions?

Comment: `person(Name, Age, Address) -> #{name = Name, age = Age, address = Address}.`?

Comment: Actually it should look like this:

person(Name, Age, Address) -> 
 #{name=>Name, age=>Age, address=>Address}.

but after I call function it returns ** exception error: undefined function testiranja:person/3. I'll take a look. Ty on hint :)

Comment: @mrjoe: There is `-export([person/3]).` missing in your `testiranja` module.

Comment: @Hynek -Pichi- Vychodil no, I had that, but eclipse was problem.I tried using notepad++ and erlang shell, everything si working fine :)

So the solution is:

`person(Name, Age, Address) -> #{name=>Name, age=>Age, address=>Address}.`

Answer (score 2):

DO you really required a function to do that? It can be directly done using record. Any way here is the code. Some places people use define statement to achieve same like constructor of oop. you can use that method if you are searching for same ...

```
-module(test).
-export([init/0, person/3]).

-record(person, {name,age,address}).
-define(PERSON(Name, Age, Address), #person{name=Name, age=Age, address=Address}).


init()->
        ?PERSON("Kermit the frog", 60, "123 Sesame street").

person(Name, Age, Address)->
        #person{name=Name, age=Age, address=Address}.
```

Comment: yes in my  task was required to do this with function :)

Comment: do you know maybe how to solve this:

Implement a function:
llen(ListOfLists)
which returns a list containing the lengths of the lists in ListOfLists.
Your function should use lists:map/2.

Example:
1> funs:llen([[1, 2, 3], [], [4, 5]]).
[3, 0, 2]

I know how to make function to get len of list:


`list_len([]) -> 0;
list_len([_|T]) -> 1+list_len(T).`